# Docusign Receipient's View

Tags: docusignapi

In the Query Parameter to GET Docusign Envelope Recipient's view, where the GET call is "/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/combined?recipient_id=123&documents_by_userid=false", is the recipient_id, the GUID generated by docusign or is the ID the one we have to pass in the Envelope create call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Recipient ID is the one passed in the Envelope Creation call (unless you're using Composite Templates, which may result in your recipient IDs being collapsed into 1, 2, 3...). If you're not certain what your recipient IDs are, make a GetRecipients call first and look for the `RecipientId` parameter in question.

I was able to get a limited view of the combined documents (only showing the documents that recipient was able to view) by doing GET `/envelopes/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx/documents/combined?recipient_id=63189929`. I had sent out of the web console, so my recipients had random integers for IDs.

If this isn't working for you, I'd recommend opening a [Support Case](https://support.docusign.com/). If you do, please include your Envelope ID and an [API log](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) of your attempt to download the combined documents.

Answer (score 0):

First, off this is not what we call recipient view. This call is for downloading the actual envelope and its documents. There's a different [POST call](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopeviews/createrecipient/) to generated a recipient view.
As for **recipientId** it is the one you specified when you created the envelope, it doesn't have to be a GUID it can be "1" or whatever you want it to be.

Comment: Yes, we actually want to download the Recipient's version/view of the package and save it, not just generate a view, after all the signatures are complete. For audit purposes, we are saving individual versions of the same envelope with signatures back in our data after receiving a signature complete notification.

Comment: To rephrase, download recipient's version of the actual and complete envelope.

Comment: You can only do that if you authenticate as that recipient. As the sender, you can only see the sender's version.

Comment: The API Spec does not say this and only talks about the query parameter. So we assumed this is doable. How else can this be accomplished? I see that the "POST" call you mentioned is only for "Sent" status and not for completed docs. Does the notification event in Docusign Connect service (Admin portal) capture this when enabled? Right now we are only capturing recipient events. Are there any other API Calls I can make to get a recipient's completed docs?

Comment: How do you expect recipient's completed docs to be different from sender's complete doc? the only difference in the DocuSign system is in the audit trail when it comes to who viewed the document

Comment: When there are multiple recipients, the recipient may not be seeing the documents on which they do not sign. There is recipient level visibility enabled. The sender might be looking at the whole envelope and the recipient maybe looking at a subset of that envelope. We want to capture the completed subset as well and save it against that recipient.

Comment: The endpoint you had in your question only lists the documents, it doesn't grab them.

Comment: The only way I know of doing what you're asking would be to authenticate as the user that you need and call the API as that user, you can use JWT with impersonation to do that without having the user have to log in .

Comment: The endpoint in my question did give us a completed document or envelope to begin with. We were able to grab Base64 as a whole and persist it. So given the query parameters, we were also hoping to grab another Base64 (recipient version) and persist as well. Even if it lists individual documents for that recipient, we are fine as we can combine them and persist as long as the "view/subset" is for that recipient. Is this possible?

Comment: The recipients are end clients and all we possibly have is their names and emails,  just a random janesmith@email who buys a product and signs a agreement. Not sure JWT impersonation is a possibility here.